# How can I implement my own documentation search function?

Tags: documentation, searching

The current documentation search doesn't allow for very sophisticate searching, can I write my own function to search through the docs?

Comment: Not directly related, but may be you have some ideas regarding this problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/212649/280 ?

Answer (score 10):

#### Update

This code is no longer the most up-to-date. The properly up-to-date code is in the [package on GitHub](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/OldHelpBrowser.wl).

For a run-down of the changes between this and that see the discussion between b3m2a1 and Nasser that starts [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40418114#40418114) and the commit messages.

---

The key here will be that all properly written documentation pages have a `"Metadata"` [`TaggingRule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TaggingRules.html).

Then we can use the `PacletManager` to search and scrape all of this. First we'll build an index of all this stuff and put it in `$helpSearcherDocData`

```
loadDocumentationData[] :=
 $helpSearcherDocData =
  Append[#,
     "Pages" ->
      Apply[Join]@
       Map[FileNames["*.nb", Last[#], \[Infinity]] &, #["Directories"]]
     ] &@
   <|
    "Directories" ->
     Join[
      DeleteDuplicatesBy[#[[1]]["Name"] &]@
       Select[DirectoryQ@*Last]@
        Map[
         # -> FileNameJoin[{#["Location"], "Documentation"}] &,
         PacletFind["*"]
         ],
      {"System" -> FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation"}]}
    |>

loadDocumentationMetadata[] :=
 (
  If[! AssociationQ@$helpSearcherDocData, loadDocumentationData[]];
  $helpSearcherDocData["Metadata"] =
   Association@
    Map[
     # :>
       Set[
        $helpSearcherDocData["Metadata", #],
        Append[
         Fold[Association@Lookup[#, #2, {}] &, 
          Options[Import[#]], {TaggingRules, "Metadata"}],
         "File" -> #
         ]
        ] &,
     $helpSearcherDocData["Pages"]
     ]
  )

ensureLoadedDocumentationMetadata[] :=

 If[! AssociationQ@$helpSearcherDocData || ! 
    KeyMemberQ[$helpSearcherDocData, "Metadata"],
  loadDocumentationMetadata[]
  ]

preLoadDocumentationMetadata[] :=

(ensureLoadedDocumentationMetadata[]; 
  Scan[Identity, $helpSearcherDocData["Metadata"]])

preLoadDocumentationMetadata[]
```

For convenience we can then cache all this, so it's quicker to load later:

```
loadCachedDocumentationData[] :=
  $helpSearcherDocData = 
   Get[LocalObject["docsDataCache"]];
cacheDocumentationData[] :=

  Put[$helpSearcherDocData, LocalObject["docsDataCache"]];
```

Then we can do simple searches on this `"Metadata"` dataset:

```
$helpSearcherDocMetadataDS :=
  $helpSearcherDocMetadataDS =
   (
    preLoadDocumentationMetadata[];
    Dataset@
     Select[Values@$helpSearcherDocData["Metadata"], KeyMemberQ["uri"]]
    );

$helpSearcherDocMetadataDS[
   Select[Length[#history] > 1 && 
      0 < ToExpression@#history[[1]] < 8 &],
   "context"
   ] // DeleteDuplicates // Normal

{"JLink`", "NETLink`", "WebServices`", "ClusterIntegration`", "", \
"GUIKit`"}
```

This gives us the contexts that were documented before version 8.

We can then do searches on any of the following properties:

```
$helpSearcherDocMetadataDS[All, Keys] // Flatten // 
  DeleteDuplicates // Normal

{"built", "history", "context", "keywords", "specialkeywords", \
"tutorialcollectionlinks", "index", "label", "language", "paclet", \
"status", "summary", "synonyms", "tabletags", "title", \
"titlemodifier", "windowtitle", "type", "uri", "File"}
```

For instance let's get all of the obsolete functions:

```
$helpSearcherDocMetadataDS[All, "status"] // Flatten // 
  DeleteDuplicates // Normal

{"None", "ObsoleteFlag"}

$helpSearcherDocMetadataDS[
  Select[#type === "Symbol" && #status === "ObsoleteFlag" &], 
  StringRiffle[URLParse[#["uri"], "Path"][[{1, -1}]], "`"] &
  ] // Normal

{"GUIKit`BindEvent", "GUIKit`CloseGUIObject", \
"GUIKit`ExposeWidgetReferences", "GUIKit`GUIInformation", \
"GUIKit`GUILoad", "GUIKit`GUIObject", "GUIKit`GUIObjectQ", \
"GUIKit`GUIResolve", "GUIKit`GUIRunModal", "GUIKit`GUIRun", \
"GUIKit`GUIScreenShot", "GUIKit`IncludedScriptContexts", \
"GUIKit`InitialArguments", "GUIKit`InvokeMethod", \
"GUIKit`InvokeThread", "GUIKit`InvokeWait", "GUIKit`Name", \
"GUIKit`PropertyValue", "GUIKit`ReleaseGUIObject", \
"GUIKit`ReleaseMethod", "GUIKit`ReturnScript", "GUIKit`Script", \
"GUIKit`ScriptSource", "GUIKit`SetPropertyValue", \
"GUIKit`SetWidgetReference", "GUIKit`SymbolicGUIKitXMLToWidget", \
"GUIKit`Tabs", "GUIKit`UnsetWidgetReference", "GUIKit`WidgetAlign", \
"GUIKit`WidgetFill", "GUIKit`WidgetGroup", "GUIKit`WidgetLayout", \
"GUIKit`Widget", "GUIKit`WidgetReference", "GUIKit`WidgetSpace", \
"GUIKit`WidgetToSymbolicGUIKitXML", "GUIKit`$GUIPath"}
```

From this data an update to the [old help browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779835/making-a-working-copy-of-the-legacy-documentation-for-version-5-inside-new-versi) could even be rebuilt

Finally, here's a proper doc searcher that returns links to the proper doc pages:

```
helpSearch[selectionFunction_] :=

 Hyperlink[#, "paclet:" <> #2, 
    BaseStyle -> "Link"] & @@@
  $helpSearcherDocMetadataDS[
   Select[selectionFunction],
   {"title", "uri"}
   ]
```

Repeating that obsolescence search:

```
helpSearch[#type === "Symbol" && #status === "ObsoleteFlag" &]
```

[image: search result]

And clicking any of those links opens up the doc page:

[image: click result]