# Can I implement something like the old documentation help browser?

Tags: customization, documentation

Old versions of Mathematica had a help browser that was more click through and structured. How can I reimplement something like that for the new (since v6) docs?

Answer (score 13):

#### Update

This code is no longer the most up-to-date. The properly up-to-date code is in the [package on GitHub](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/OldHelpBrowser.wl).

For a run-down of the changes between this and that see the discussion between b3m2a1 and Nasser that starts [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40418114#40418114)

---

#### Update 2

This package has now been merged with the documentation search package, allowing one to perform searches and open them in an old-style browser. For example, one can search like so:

```
HelpPagesSearch[{
  "status" -> "ObsoleteFlag",
  "type" -> "Tutorial",
  "context" -> "System`"
  }, True]
```

[image: search results]

And then these links will open in the old-style help browser:

[image: open img]

---

#### Original

We'll build off of my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157304/38205).

The basic idea will just be to make a `DockedCell` click through interface that will load the new pages in the notebook.

First we'll need to load and organize the data in a tree structure:

```
helpBrowserCoreDS :=
  helpBrowserCoreDS =
   GroupBy[
    $helpSearcherDocMetadataDS,
    Key["type"] -> KeyDrop["type"],
    GroupBy[Key["context"] -> KeyDrop["context"]]
    ];
```

Then we can make a little click through `Dataset` where we can open the doc notebooks, rather than load them in notebook:

```
helpBrowserDSButton[entry_, onClick_] :=
  Column[{
    Button[#,
       onClick["paclet:" <> #2, #],
       BaseStyle -> "Hyperlink",
       Appearance -> None,
       Method -> "Queued"
       ] & @@ Lookup[entry, {"title", "uri"}],
    If[StringQ@#,
       Pane[#, {400, UpTo[250]}, ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable"],
       #
       ] &@Lookup[entry, "summary", Nothing]
    }];
helpBrowserDS[
  formatFunction_: helpBrowserDSButton,
  onClick_: Documentation`HelpLookup
  ] :=
 Map[
   Association@*
    Map[
     Lookup[#, "title"] ->
       formatFunction[#, onClick]
      &
     ]
   ] /@ helpBrowserCoreDS
```

This is nice for quick stuff.

Or we can build out a proper click through interface with `ListPicker`:

```
helpBrowserDockedCell[path : _List : {}] :=
  DynamicModule[
   {
    panePath = path,
    panePicker,
    coreDS,
    setNB,
    showBrowser = True
    },
   coreDS = 
    Normal@helpBrowserDS["paclet:" <> Lookup[#, {"uri"}, ""] &, 
      Null];
   panePicker =
    Function@
     With[{
       choices = #, idx = #2
       },
      ListPicker[
       Dynamic[
        If[Length@panePath >= idx, panePath[[{idx}]]],
        Function@
         Set[
          panePath,
          ReplacePart[
           If[Length@panePath >= idx,
            Take[panePath, idx],
            PadRight[panePath, idx, ""]
            ], idx -> First@#]
          ]
        ],
       choices,
       ImageSize -> {150, 150},
       Background -> {{GrayLevel[.95], White}}
       ]
      ];
   setNB =
    Function[
     CheckAll[
      FrontEndExecute@
       FrontEnd`NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates[EvaluationNotebook[]];
      SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Notebook];
      SetOptions[NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
       Deletable -> True];
      NotebookDelete[EvaluationNotebook[]];
      With[{
        nb =
         DeleteCases[
           WindowSize | WindowMargins | DockedCells | 
             StyleDefinitions -> _]@
          Replace[Documentation`ResolveLink[#], {
            f_String?FileExistsQ :> Import[f],
            _ -> Notebook[{}]
            }]
        },
       NotebookWrite[
        EvaluationNotebook[],
        First@nb
        ];
       SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
        Join[
         {
          StyleDefinitions ->

           FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb", 
            CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]
          },
         List @@ Rest@nb
         ]
        ]
       ];
      SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, Notebook];
      FrontEndExecute@
       FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[EvaluationNotebook[]],
      FrontEndExecute@
       FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[EvaluationNotebook[]]
      ];
     Nothing
     ];
   Dynamic@
    If[showBrowser,
     Column[{
       Button["Hide Browser",
        showBrowser = False,
        Appearance -> None,
        BaseStyle -> "Hyperlink"
        ],
       Row@
        Prepend[
         MapIndexed[
          Replace[
            coreDS @@ Take[panePath, #2[[1]]], {
             a_Association :> panePicker[a // Keys, #2[[1]] + 1],
             e_ :> setNB[e]
             }] &,
          panePath
          ],
         panePicker[Keys[coreDS], 1]
         ]
       }],
     Button["Show Browser",
      showBrowser = True,
      Appearance -> None,
      BaseStyle -> "Hyperlink"
      ]
     ]
   ];

helpBrowserNotebook[path : _List : {}] :=
  Notebook[{},
   DockedCells ->
    Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@helpBrowserDockedCell[path],
     CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}},
     CellMargins -> None,
     CellFrameMargins -> None
     ],
   System`ClosingSaveDialog -> False,
   Saveable -> False,
   WindowTitle -> "Help Browser"
   ];
```

And finally a top-level function to implement this:

```
OpenHelpBrowser[path : _List : {}] :=

 If[MatchQ[$helpBrowser, _NotebookObject?(NotebookRead[#] =!= $Failed \
&)],
  SetOptions[$helpBrowser, {
    WindowFloating -> True,
    Visible -> True
    }];
  SetOptions[$helpBrowser, WindowFloating -> False],
  $helpBrowser = CreateDocument@helpBrowserNotebook[]
  ]
```

And when we run this:

```
OpenHelpBrowser[]

NotebookObject[FrontEndObject[LinkObject["w7er3_shm", 3, 1]], 59]
```

[image: interface]

Finally I packaged this all up [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/OldHelpBrowser.wl) so you can use it like:

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/OldHelpBrowser.wl"];
OpenHelpBrowser[]
```

Note it'll be very slow the first time while it builds the index, but then it caches it every usage after that will be fast.