# Is it possible to turn "FunctionResource" Notebook into ResourceObject or registered LocalObject without FrontEnd?

Tags: notebooks, conversion, cloud-deploy, resourceobject, resourcefunction

### TL;DR

**The problem boils down to how to convert a correctly prepared submission Notebook into a `ResourceObject` suitable for `ResourceSubmit`, using the [Free Wolfram Engine for Developers](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) or the [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/).** The [Free Wolfram Engine for Developers](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) doesn't support `NotebookObject`, and hence the last example on the Documentation page for [`ResourceSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceSubmit.html) doesn't work.  And it also doesn't work in the [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/), despite the fact that the latter supports  `NotebookObject`! I'm asking for a way to do the conversion without intermediate `NotebookObject`. I hope it is possible.

---

One can obtain the "FunctionResource" submission Notebook template by evaluating the following in *Mathematica* or in the Cloud:

```
nbo = CreateNotebook["FunctionResource"];
```

After filling the template it can be converted into a `ResourceObject` simply by applying `ResourceObject` to the `NotebookObject` handle returned by `CreateNotebook`:

```
funResource = ResourceObject[nbo];
```

Now the resource can be submitted using `ResourceSubmit`:

```
ResourceSubmit[funResource, "PublisherID" -> "MyPublisherID"];
```

I'm currently working with the [Free Wolfram Engine for Developers](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) (FWED) which doesn't support `NotebookObject` handle, and hence the above code doesn't work. I have a "FunctionResource" Notebook prepared some time ago on another machine with *Mathematica* 12.0 and wish to submit it to the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) using [`ResourceSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceSubmit.html) which is available in FWED and works (at least submission of a `"DataResource"` `ResourceObject` as shown on the Docs page for [`ResourceSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceSubmit.html) was successful).

The above code was adapted from the second example on [`ResourceSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceSubmit.html) page which shows how it is possible to turn an opened "DataResource" submission Notebook (available as a `NotebookObject`) into an actual `ResourceObject`:

> Open a definition notebook and create a new data resource:
>
> ```
> nbo = CreateNotebook["DataResource"]
> ```
>
> > [image: output1]
>
> ```
> dogResource = ResourceObject[nbo]
> ```
>
> > [image: output2]

Note that [`ResourceSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceSubmit.html) page seems to be the only place in the Documentation where this functionality is described. A direct attempt to supply a `Notebook` expression results in error:

> ResourceObject::defkey: The resource must have a value for Name.

`ResourceObject` and `ResourceRegister` pages describe how to convert a `LocalObject` or `CloudObject` into a `ResourceObject` object and register it in order to have it available by name:

> `ResourceObject[loc]` accepts locations of previous resource object deployments including `LocalObject` and `CloudObject`.
>
> ---
>
> Registering the resource allows it to be discovered by name:
>
> ```
> ResourceRegister[ro];
> ResourceObject["English Words"]
> ```
>
> > [image: output]

Hence it should be sufficient to find a way to convert "FunctionResource" Notebook into correct `LocalObject` for turning it on the next step into an `NotebookObject`.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be achieved?